# Why my byte array size increase on the client side

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, serialization

I send a byte array from my web server to my client :

```
byte[myByteArray] = null;
// filling myByteArray
return Json(myByteArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and myByteArray contains 480000 bytes so basically it should be around 480KB

but when I send it to my client and I watch the Network section on chrome console, the response size is over 1.5MB

Why ? My first answer that comes to my mind is the serialization , if it is the case , how can I send a byteArray without Serializing it, as file maybe ?

Comment: Please show us the first 200 characters of the JSON payload you are returning to the client.

Comment: Yes, a byte[] encoded inside json will be pretty large by default. Your best bet might be to base-64 encode the data (Convert.ToBase64String), so you're actually just sending a string, and then decode that at the client.

Comment: thank you , you are my hero saver !